# nextjs make multiple request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I don't know why it did this i am learning nextjs and i am trying but nextjs makes multiple request.I want to pull my own data but the page looks weird as i said i am new to nextjs.
[image]

```
    export default function Product() {
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsloading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/products");
        const data = await res.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setError(err);
      }
      setIsloading(false);
    };
    fetchData();


  }, [])


  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }
  if (error) {
    return <h1>Error: {error.message}</h1>
  }
  console.log(data.data);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data.data.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.id}>
            <h2>{product.attributes.name}</h2>
            <code>{product.attributes.price}</code>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```